# International Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, release-hera, language

I just installed version 5.1 and need to type in Spanish. I can't find where to add the international layout to the keyboard. It does not appear on the keyboard layout options on system settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]`System Settings` > `Keyboard` > `+` in the lower-right corner > Select `Spanish` and click `Add Layout`.

Then you'll be able to switch between your current layout and Spanish layout in the menubar of via shortcut.